# impersonator working with no local user account

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.5, impersonation

I am using an impersonator from code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User

I have implemented this correctly and seems to be working, but I don't think it should be.

I have implemented it in a .NET 4.5 WCF application running under IIS 7.5 locally (not express of VS Dev Server) and when calling the impersonator method passing a user name and password it works fine, but the user does not exist under my local machine.

Is their a setting in IIS or Windows 7 somewhere that allows impersonation when a User account does not exist??

Comment: Just to clarify - the user account you are trying to impersonate is a valid domain account?

Comment: no thats my point, the credentials I supply to the impersonator dont exist on the machine the app is running on. Also, the machine is not connected to a domain

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".